# How to delete rabbitmq shovels through commandline

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmq-shovel

I created shovels using ,
rabbitmqctl set_parameter shovel "MyShovel" ......

Now i want to delete it,
Can you please tell me on how to achieve it using commandline.

Comment: I am using it in windows. i tried using ,                                         
         rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_shovel_status:remove({"MyShovel"}).'             I get error as below,                                                                                     
 Error: syntax error before:

Comment: This command,                                                                            
 rabbitmqctl eval "rabbit_shovel_status:remove({'/','TestShovel'})." returns Ok. But i still dont see shovel getting deleted.  FYI,TestShovel status is in terminated state.

Comment: Can anyone please help me

Comment: rabbitmqctl clear_parameter shovel MyShovel. This command works for delete shovel through command line

Comment: rabbitmqctl takes longer time to process creation and deletion of shovel. Can we achieve it using rabbitmqadmin

Comment: rabbitmqadmin usage to delete a single shovel as below,                            
rabbitmqadmin.py delete parameter component=shovel name=MyShovel .. It responds very quickly within a second
rabbitmqctl usage:
rabbitmqctl clear_parameter shovel myshovel  takes little more time.Close to 6 seconds. 

I feel rabbitmqadmin is faster in response. Is it expected behaviour.

Comment: Now,I am trying to find a way to create shovels using rabbitmqadmin. The below command i am using,
rabbitmqadmin.py -V localhost declare parameter component=shovel name=MyShovel value="{""ack-mode"": ""on-publish"",""add-forward-headers"": false,""delete-after"": ""never"",""dest-uri"": [""127.0.0.1""],""dest-exchange"":""TestExchange"",""src-queue"": ""myqueue"",""src-uri"": [""127.0.0.1""]}"

I get error as follows,
*** Not found: /api/parameters/shovel/localhost/MyShovel

Any idea? Please tell me what mistake i am doing here in command. I am performing this on windows.

Comment: rabbitmqadmin.py declare parameter component=shovel name=MyShovel value="{""ack-mode"": ""on-publish"",""add-forward-headers"": false,""delete-after"": ""never"",""dest-uri"": [""amqp://tester:tester@localhost""],""dest-exchange"":""ControlExchange"",""src-queue"": ""myqueue"",""src-uri"": [""amqp://tester:tester@localhost""]}"                                                    I removed the -V localhost parameter.I also changed the source and dest uri declaration to proper uris. and it works. Hope this helps to other members here

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works more or less instantly:

```
rabbitmqctl clear_parameter shovel MyShovel
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to delete a shovel that contains spaces in the name? I tried `rabbitmqctl clear_parameter shovel 'Move from the-dead-letter'` but that syntax appears incorrect. I have 3 of these zombie shovels.

Comment: @LeeGrissom I haven't tried doing that specifically, but I do remember running into an issue where I had to URL-encode the password to a Rabbit queue when setting up a shovel (if the password contains certain characters). So, maybe try URL-encoding the shovel name? => `Move%20from%20the-dead-letter`

Comment: I tried that just now and same result. I also tried surrounding the parameter with double-quotes " ", but I get the same error message:  `Error: Parameter does not exist.` I'm starting to think the syntax might not be the problem in my situation. I might have a bigger problem going on. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also list and delete shovels from the command line using `rabbitmqadmin`

Listing Shovels command

```
rabbitmqadmin --host=HOST --port=443 --ssl --vhost=/ --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD -f tsv -q list parameters name component
```

Delete a Shovel command

```
rabbitmqadmin --host=HOST --port=443 --ssl --vhost=/ --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD -f tsv -q delete parameter component=shovel name=nameOfShovel
```